# Angular 9 upgrade CompilerFactory errors

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, angular-ivy, angular-upgrade

I upgrade angular from 8.2.2 to 9.1.8 according to the official upgrade

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.6
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.8
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.6
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.6
@angular/cli                      9.1.6
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.6
@schematics/angular               9.1.6
@schematics/update                0.901.6
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.6.4
webpack                           4.42.0
```

I am getting errors on CompilerFactory

```
Uncaught NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CompilerFactory]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for CompilerFactory!
```

Below is the main.ts file

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I checked online, that since angular 9 support Ivy, so the platformBrowserDynamic() should change to platformBrowser().  I change the main.ts to

```
 platformBrowser().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

But still get the same No provider for CompilerFactory error. 
Then I change the main.ts to below

```
 platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(<any>AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

and getting a different error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Below is difference that add on angular 9 in angular.json file

```
 "options": {
            "aot": true,
}
   "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I have to update one of the kendo library to make it work